# Looking for main class outside of classpath?

Tags: java, user-interface, classpath, classloader, manifest

I've been given a manifest file of:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.2

Main-Class: AboutApplication

Class-Path: multimedia.jar
```

multimedia.jar has plenty of helper classes I need, but the main method is in AboutApplication, which is in a jar called About.jar

This was the manifest file that was given, is there a way to use class loaders to get to my main method and use the multimedia.jars classes?

Here is the class with the main method:

```
public class AboutApplication extends MultimediaApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new AboutApplication(args, 400, 600));
  }

  public AboutApplication(String[] args, int width, int height)
  {
    super(args, new AboutApp(), width, height);
  }
}
```

This method extends classes derived from multimedia.jar

Comment: Usually the `main` method is called from the command line - what are you trying to do?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've created a few classes that use some classes in multimedia.jar. Two of the classes have main methods, one is just a class that adds to a GUI. Basically it's a program that cuts down on duplicate code and only uses one class for creating a GUI in both an applet and an application. The one main method uses parameters for an application, the other for an applet. But the classes extend and implement other classes from multimedia.jar. I know I need a class loader, but am not sure how to use it.